# how to configure or enable reply time calculate with any mark shows in sent item

Tags: performance, user-agent, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker, qnetworkreply

Is there a method to configure or enable the display of reply time calculation in the sent item? I would like to examine whether my agent's email responses were within the allotted time frame by observing a green or red mark.